# UITableView semi-sticky tableViewHeader like App Store detail view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm looking to have a semi-sticky `tableViewHeader` just like the iOS7 app store detail view. The detail view is the screen with the Details | Reviews | Related `UISegementedControl` where you actually download the app. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to post images, but it starts off normally at the top. As you scroll up, it scrolls normally as well. However, once the `UISegementedControl` hits the top, it sticks. I am going to have multiple sections in the table.

I've gotten this to work correctly visually using auto layout by adding the top view as the tableHeaderView and intercepting the scrollViewDidScroll event:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
     if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 69) //offset from top to uisegmentedcontrol
          self.toolBarHeightToTop.constant = scrollView.contentOffset.y; //toolBarHeightToTop is auto layout constraint from uisegmentedcontrol to top of header
     else
          self.toolBarHeightToTop.constant = 69; //default
}
```

However, the `UISegmentedControl` does not detect touch events. Instead, the `UITableView` delegate method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is raised. Any ideas?

Comment: It's standard section header. What is the problem?

Comment: I am going to have multiple sections, so to me it makes sense to have it in the tableHeaderView as opposed to the section header. Is that not correct?

Comment: In that case how about manually manage the layout in a regular `UIViewController`? `UISegmentedControl` above a `UITableView`.

Comment: And `tableHeaderView` shouldn't invoke `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Are you sure it is really a header view?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this too: I need the top header section to scroll with the UITableView because I am using MSPullToRefresh and the specs call for everything to scroll together.

Comment: @Desdenova I think the issue is that the UITableViewCells are under the UISegmentedControl when overlayed so for some reason it interprets the touch as clicking the UITableViewCell instead of the UISegmentedControl

Comment: If so you can easily disable selection for that specific cell by returning `NO` here `tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:` for that `NSIndexPath`

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't detect the UISegmentedControl getting pressed.

Comment: In addition of what other answers said about the tableview header section, I think the blurry effect is made with a UIToolbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the header and the segmented control are `UITableView` Header's and the content below the segmented control belongs in a `UITableViewCell`

The header (above the `UISegmentedControl`) is in a `UITableView` section that doesn't have any rows (but it does have a header).

The `UISegmentedControl` is the header of a `UITableView` section that has 1 row - the content  that you see and a header - the `UISegmentedControl`

Comment: I should have specified, but I am going to have multiple sections in the table

Comment: @user3091519 - how does that make a difference?

Comment: Because won't the top two section headers (header and UISegmentedControl) scroll off the screen when the user scrolls down far enough?

Comment: If you need the `UISegmentedControl` header to stay on screen, then can you put all your content in `UITableViewCell`'s in that section? Or do you need other sticky headers for other sections?

Comment: I think pre-iOS 7 did something similar that didn't use this same method, I think it manually handled moving the header. But this approach appears to be by far the best.

Comment: I need sticky headers in the other sections. It is a table that will be sectioned off by date so each section will have a header that indicates what date the row is under.